# Estimating the rate of convergence, finite difference scheme

Tags: math

I'm trying to estimate the rate of convergence of a sequence.

background:

u^n+1 = G u_n, where G is a iteration matrix (coming from heat equation).

Fixing dx = 0.1, and setting dt = dx*dx/2.0 to satisfy the a stability constraint
I then do a number of iterations up to time T = 0.1, and calculate the error (analytical solution is known) using max-norm.

This gives me a sequence of global errors, which from the theory should be of the form O(dt) + O(dx^2).

Now, I want to confirm that we have O(dt).

How should I do this?

Comment: Better asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Since when Numerical Methods are outside the scope of StackOverflow?

Comment: I guess G depends on dt and dx, right ? If so, in which manner ?

Comment: @belisarius: They're not outside the scope of StackOverflow, but where do you see any reference to software or programming here?

Comment: @Jason Unless you suppose he is going to integrate iteratively the heat equation by hand ...

Comment: No, but the mathematical point of view is that there is an abstract analytical entity that expresses solutions in terms of inputs via one or more equations. The programming/computational point of view is that there are implementation details to those solutions. This question isn't about implementation but about the mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Alexandre C.'s suggestion might need a little refinement (no pun intended) because the global error estimate depends on both Δt and Δx.

So if Δx were too coarse, refining Δt by halving might not produce the expected reduction of halving the error.

A better test might then be to simultaneously reduce Δt by quartering and Δx by halving.  Then the global error estimate leads us to expect the error reduced by quartering.

Incidently it is common to plot the global error and "scales" as a log-log graph to estimate the order of convergence.

With greater resources (of time and computer runs) independently varying the time and space discretizations would allow a two-parameter fit (of the same sort of log-log model).

Comment: you're obviously right. If OP uses some kind of explicit scheme, suggesting to "set dx to very small" and make dt vary is not good at all either (since the scheme will likely be unstable when dt > k dx^2). Nonetheless, your answer heavily depends on guessing what the joint dependence of dx and dt is. I therefore keep my suggesion as is, and rely on OP's good sense of 1) what a stable scheme means and 2) independently assess the convergence in x and in t.

Comment: And also, OP explicitly states that it takes dx = f(dt) so that its CFL condition is ok, so we really have one variable here.

Answer (score 1):

Relaunch the same code with dt/2 and witness the error being halved.

Answer (score 0):

I suck at physics, but simple problems like this, even I can do.

Well, with what do you have problem with?

### Calculating  rate of the convergence:

1. If you have series defined as [image] ( `Sum[a[n], {n, 1, Infinity}]` ), then you need to find location, where the series converges  [image] ( `L=Limit[a[n], n -> Infinity]` ).
2. Now you can find the rate of the convergence [image] ( `μ = Limit[(a[n + 1] - L)/(a[n] - L),  n -> Infinity]` )

### Finding the combined uncertainty with analytical solution

Using the equation:
[image] ( `Uc = 
 Sqrt[(D[a, t]  Δt)^2 + (D[a, x]  Δx)^2]` )